# Use custom font with ezdxf

Tags: python, dxf, ezdxf

I would like to write a text with a custom ttf on a dxf using ezdxf.

I tried using `doc.styles.new('custom_font', dxfattribs={'font' : 'myFont.ttf'})` to load the ttf file (which is in the same folder as my script), but it doesn't work.

My code:

```
import ezdxf

doc = ezdxf.new('R12', setup=True)
msp = doc.modelspace()

doc.styles.new('custom_style', dxfattribs={'font': 'myFont.ttf'})

text_to_export = ex.text_to_export.text()

msp.add_text(text_to_export,
             dxfattribs={
                  'style': "custom_style",
                  'height': 0.35}
             ).set_pos((2, 6), align='LEFT')

doc.saveas("text.dxf")
```

Comment: works fine for me (I fixed the missing ex.text_to_export.text()). you probably should state what you expect and how the actual behaviour differs on your platform. you also should state your OS and how you installed the font, too.